# How to add MS SQL table using python console?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, mysql

I have MS SQL Server 2008 R2 database. How to add MS SQL Table using python console in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. To help us provide a better answer, can you expand your question a little (just click edit, above) to tell us more about your specific scenario - database schema, table structure (especially the geometry) and whether you are doing this on the local machine or to a remote server?

Comment: My database is on the local machine. I have a table with 2 fields:id (int) and shape(geography).

Comment: Mari: Its easier to understand if you actually update the question, rather than just putting the details in comments. You can amend the question text by clicking "edit" below the question.

Answer (score 3):

Each data provider has its **URI** and its **provider key**. Once added via User Interface, it's easy to collect them and use them from the console.

Enter this statement in your python console, to collect the URI and key for all map layers:

```py
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    uri = layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
    providerKey = layer.dataProvider().name()
    print("URI:\n%s\nKey:\n%s\n" % (uri, providerKey))
```

to create a new map layer based on this information:

### Vector Layer

```py
vl = QgsVectorLayer( uri, 'MyLayerName', providerKey )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers( [vl] )
```

### Raster Layer

```py
rl = QgsRasterLayer( uri, 'MyLayerName', providerKey )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers( [rl] )
```

The key for MS SQL is 'mssql'

The uri follow the QgsDataSourceURI standard, which has an example in the [PyQGIS cookbook chapter Loading Layers, Vector Layers](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers). MS SQL works analogue to postgres.

The above example duplicates just one layer, but prints the necessary information to add each of them and gives an idea about the principle.